# How to solve "didn't return an HttpResponse object" error?

Tags: python, django

I have a delete button. I use the same structure in other views and it is working correclty. But in this page it did not work. When I want to delete a comment there is an error:

> ValueError at /comment/18/analysis/ The view
> ocr.views.delete_approval_comment didn't return an HttpResponse
> object. It returned None instead.

It deletes the comment but gives this error. How can I solve it?

**views.py**

```
def delete_approval_comment(request,id):
    comment = CommentFromOthers.objects.get(id=id)
    comment.delete()
    redirect('ocr', comment.doc_id.id)
```

**ocr.html**

```
...
<a href="{% url 'delete_app_comment' comment.id %}" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"
                                               onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?')"
>
    <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
...
```

**urls.py**

```
...
url(r'^ocrs/(?P<id>\d+)/analysis/$', views.ocr, name="ocr"),
url(r'^comment/(?P<id>\d+)/analysis/$', views.delete_approval_comment, name="delete_app_comment"),
...
```

Comment: you forgot to return the redirect(), add ```return redirect('ocr', comment.doc_id.id)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function does not return anything !!!

You must do this :

```
return redirect('ocr', comment.doc_id.id)
```

for example :

```
def my_view(request):
    ...
    return redirect('/some/url/')

def my_view(request):
    ...
    return redirect('https://example.com/')
```

[For more explanation, you can read the Django document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/shortcuts/)